# wordpress connect to PayPal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I am getting an error of below when i try to integrate my Wordpress woocommerce with pal.
In the Payments tab when i install Paypal plugin blue button should appear to connect the Site plugin with the Paypal account.instead of that i am getting below message.

''''

We could not properly connect to PayPal. Try reloading the page. Could not create referral. /home/......./wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/modules/ppcp-api-client/src/Endpoint/PartnerReferrals.php:85

We could not properly connect to PayPal. Try reloading the page. Could not create referral. /home/....../wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/modules/ppcp-api-client/src/Endpoint/PartnerReferrals.php:85

'''

Have looking through the web to find a solution for this but with no luck,Did any one of you came across with this.Please help.

Comment: Which Paypal plugin u are using ? Also try this https://woocommerce.com/document/how-to-test-for-conflicts/

Comment: This will be WooCommerce PayPal Payments